# How do you switch an active SQL Server database into Simple Recovery Mode

Tags: sql-server, log-files

I've had some logging problems and based on the way the application works we don't need full recovery mode, which will help us with our logging.

How do I switch the database into simple recovery mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in SQL Managment Studio by right-clicking the database, choosing Properties, selecting Options in the menu on the left and changing the Recovery Model drop-down to Simple.

In T-SQL the command is:

```
ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
```

Comment: you don't need to restart the database do you?

Comment: Nope.  You don't really restart a database, per se.  You would restart the server instance.  In any case, you don't have to when changing the recovery model.